# How to set dynamic function to InkWell widget?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, dart, visual-studio-code

I was creating a FireBase Signing using Google and Phone in Flutter and there required two button so i created a function and passed a function in a parameter to set on onTap for Inkwell which would work different for different passing functions but there is an error.

There is my button widget

```
Widget buttonItem(
      String imagepath, String buttonName, double size, Function Tap) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: Tap, //Here its showing error IDE not allowing
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 60,
        height: 60,
        child: Card(
          color: Colors.black,
          elevation: 8,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              side: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.grey)),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              SvgPicture.asset(
                imagepath,
                height: size,
                width: size,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 15,
              ),
              Text(
                buttonName,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 17,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And here is the args passing.

```
buttonItem("assets/google.svg", "Continue with Google", 25,
                  () async {
                await authClass.googleSignIn(context);
              }),
              SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              buttonItem("assets/phone.svg", "Continue with Phone", 25, () {}),
              SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
```

[image: I don't know why i am getting this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't set the type for Inkwell Function in buttonItem, for this just define type `Function Tap` to `void Function() Tap.`

Then just try to use this one

```
Widget buttonItem(
  String imagepath, String buttonName, double size, void Function() Tap) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: Tap, //Here its showing error IDE not allowing
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 60,
        height: 60,
        child: Card(
          color: Colors.black,
          elevation: 8,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              side: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.grey)),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              SvgPicture.asset(
                imagepath,
                height: size,
                width: size,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 15,
              ),
              Text(
                buttonName,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 17,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: its not accepting. like its a syntactical error red underscore.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. While your answer is correct, it is code-only, so I doesn't explain what was originally wrong and it doesn't help OP or anybody else avoid repeating the mistake

Comment: Yup I would avoid this ...  should i delete this question ?